# Regression table for outputs from 10 countries

Tags: regression, stata

How can I combine the regression results for 10 countries in Stata?

I use just one do-file to run the regressions for each country. After running the do-file every time, I can save the results with `estout` command to a word document. In this case, I have 10 regression outcomes saved separately for each country. Do you know a nice way of combining these regressions in one or two tables at least?

Comment: If my answer answers your question, do please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and please clarify your question

Comment: thanks. I accepted the other comment as it clearly states how to save the results .dta file and then append. I clear do file after running for each country, so I needed to deal with that. Otherwise, I knew about eststo and estout commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new dataset with estimation results appending from each country, like this:

```
use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/notes/hsb2, clear
regress read female write
estimates store m1, title(Model 1)
regress read female write math
estimates store m2, title(Model 2)
regress read female write math science socst
estimates store m3, title(Model 3)
estout m1 m2 m3
keep  _est_m1 _est_m2 _est_m3
save data1.dta, replace

use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/notes/hsb2, clear
regress read female write
estimates store m4, title(Model 1)
regress read female write math
estimates store m5, title(Model 2)
regress read female write math science socst
estimates store m6, title(Model 3)
keep  _est_m4 _est_m5 _est_m6
save data2.dta, replace

use data1.dta, clear
append using data2.dta
estout m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6
     
estout m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 using "~/Desktop/Regression_results.rtf", cells(b(star fmt(3)) se(par fmt(2)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You definitely could've just googled this (as I did) and got a quicker answer but here goes:

The basic approach to do what you want is: run a model, say `reg y x`, save the estimates into an object using the `eststo` command (which is shorthand for `estimates store`), repeat this for as many models you want, and then export the saved estimates into a table using the `estout` command.

For example:

```
use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/notes/hsb2, clear

regress read female write
estimates store m1, title(Model 1)

regress read female write math
estimates store m2, title(Model 2)

regress read female write math science socst
estimates store m3, title(Model 3)

estout m1 m2 m3
---------------------------------------------------
                       m1           m2           m3
                        b            b            b
---------------------------------------------------
female          -4.532084    -2.739657    -1.328513
write            .7067537     .3924361     .1503085
math                          .4753659     .2934723
science                                    .2508791
socst                                      .2694578
_cons            17.40106     7.986659      2.44264
---------------------------------------------------
```

You can add significance stars and standard errors in parentheses below the coefficients with these options:

```
estout m1 m2 m3, cells(b(star fmt(3)) se(par fmt(2)))

------------------------------------------------------------
                       m1              m2              m3   
                     b/se            b/se            b/se   
------------------------------------------------------------
female             -4.532***       -2.740*         -1.329   
                   (1.17)          (1.09)          (1.05)   
write               0.707***        0.392***        0.150   
                   (0.06)          (0.07)          (0.08)   
math                                0.475***        0.293***
                                   (0.07)          (0.07)   
science                                             0.251***
                                                   (0.07)   
socst                                               0.269***
                                                   (0.06)   
_cons              17.401***        7.987*          2.443   
                   (3.20)          (3.23)          (3.11)   
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if you want to export to a Word document you need only specify a file name and the correct extension. E.g.

```
estout m1 m2 m3 using "~/Desktop/Regression_results.rtf", cells(b(star fmt(3)) se(par fmt(2)))
```

And then open it with MS Word.

These examples come from [this UCLA resource](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-use-estout-to-make-regression-tables-that-look-like-those-in-journal-articles/) which you can review for more info